# canon EOS 70D with 18-200 mm Lens for macro photography

Tags: canon, dslr, macro, landscape

I am a novice in photography and am interested in taking photos of natural scenes as well as physical phenomena (such as turbulence evaporation, ice crystallization and the like).

considering my budget, I am going to purchase a **Canon EOS 70D with 18-200 mm Lens** and I want to know if it is suitable for macro photography,
please note that I do not want to purchase an expensive digital camera or lenses at this stage as I am just trying to learn how to do photography and I do not need such professional quality.

please help me,

Comment: I think you're doing this backwards. You should start with "This is what I want to do and this is my budget" and from there ask "How do I work out what's best to buy?".

Comment: I think *this is what I plan to buy, but I want to check that it can do X* is an okay question. There may be a long list of other reasons that the OP chose what they did, and they just need a little help to know whether their choice will work in a given context. We deal with questions along those lines all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specs](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/ef-s-18-200mm-f-35-56-is-refurbished-17976-1) for the EF-S 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6 IS, the nearest focusing distance is 1.48 feet, and the maximum close-up magnification is 0.24x. That's not quite what you want for macro photography, where you'd really like a more magnification. But it doesn't mean that you can't use the lens, especially when you're just starting out. It helps that you'll use the lens on a crop sensor camera, where you automatically get some additional magnification compared to a full frame camera. You can get macro extension rings that move lens a little further from the sensor, increasing the magnification, the or a lens reversal attachment that lets you use the lens backward for a similar effect. So if that's the lens you want, and you just want to dabble in macro, you can probably make due until you're ready to commit more to the endeavor.